# Resolving complete intersections of quadrics with singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

Suppose that $X$ is a complete intersection of quadrics in $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb C}$. Is there some straightforward procedure to resolve the singularities of $X$?

For example, can one stratify singularities $X_{\rm sing}\subset X$ by some strata $X_1\subset X_2\subset \cdots \subset X_k=X_{\rm sing}$ so that  $X$ can be resolved in $k$ steps by blowing consequently proper transforms of $X_i$, starting with blowing up $X$ in $X_1$?

Comment: For every irreducible projective variety $Y$, there exists a Veronese re-embedding such that the isomorphic image of $Y$ is one irreducible component of a complete intersection $X$ of quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^n$, cf. Mumford, "Varieties defined by quadratic equations."  Every resolution of $X$ will also resolve $Y$.  Thus, the resolution problem for all complete intersections of quadrics is just as hard as the general resolution problem.

Comment: Very nice Jason! I must confess my ignorance here: I wasn't aware of this :(